# Typescript generic type cast error

Tags: typescript, mobx, typescript-generics

I have a utility function which helps to type check injected stores in react component

```
import { Diff } from 'typelevel-ts';
import * as React from 'react';

export type TypedInject<Stores> = <StoreKeyToInject extends keyof 
 Stores>(
 ...storeKeysToInject: StoreKeyToInject[]
 ) => <ExpectedProps extends Pick<Stores, StoreKeyToInject>>(
  component: React.ComponentType<ExpectedProps>
 ) => React.ComponentType<Diff<ExpectedProps, Pick<Stores, 
  StoreKeyToInject>>>;
```

I get an error "Type 'Pick' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof ExpectedProps'.
  Type 'Pick' is not assignable to type 'StoreKeyToInject'."

Can you please explain what it does and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you don't provide a usage example, from what I understand of your code, you want to return a new component, that will not have the stores that are passed in `storeKeysToInject`.

`Pick` picks properties from a type so `Pick<Stores, StoreKeyToInject>` is an object containing only the stores passed in to `storeKeysToInject`.

`Diff` removes keys from a type, so the second parameter must be the keys to be removed. So the conclusion is you don't really need the `Pick` you just need to remove `StoreKeyToInject` from `ExpectedProps` (`StoreKeyToInject` will already be a key of `Stores` so there is no need to bring `Stores` into the discussion again)

```
export type TypedInject<Stores> = 
    <StoreKeyToInject extends keyof Stores>(...storeKeysToInject: StoreKeyToInject[]) 
        => <ExpectedProps extends Pick<Stores, StoreKeyToInject>> (component: React.ComponentType<ExpectedProps>) 
            => React.ComponentType<Diff<ExpectedProps, StoreKeyToInject>>;
```